# The fetch() API in the Action function is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I've thoroughly tested the backend using Postman and it's responding correctly. However, despite extensive debugging efforts, the frontend isn't receiving the expected response. I've reviewed the code multiple times but can't identify the issue. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate, Link, Form } from "react-router-dom";

import Card from "../Utility/Card";
import "./Authentication.css";
import { validateEmail, validatePassword } from "../Utility/Validator";

const SignupPage = () => {
  const [emailIsValid, setEmailIsValid] = useState(true);
  const [passwordIsValid, setPasswordIsValid] = useState(true);
  const [confirmPasswordIsValid, setConfirmPasswordIsValid] = useState(true);

  const emailInputRef = useRef();
  const passwordInputRef = useRef();
  const confirmPasswordInputRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    emailInputRef.current.focus();
  }, []);

  // const navigate = useNavigate();

  let isEmail;
  let isPassword;

  const formSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const enteredEmail = emailInputRef.current.value;
    const enteredPassword = passwordInputRef.current.value;
    const enteredConfirmPassword = confirmPasswordInputRef.current.value;

    isEmail = validateEmail(enteredEmail);
    isPassword = validatePassword(enteredPassword);

    if (!isEmail) {
      setEmailIsValid(false);
    }

    if (!isPassword) {
      setPasswordIsValid(false);
    }

    if (enteredConfirmPassword !== enteredPassword) {
      setConfirmPasswordIsValid(false);
    }
  };

  const emailChangeHandler = () => {
    setEmailIsValid(true);
  };
  const passwordChangeHandler = () => {
    setPasswordIsValid(true);
  };
  const confirmPasswordChangeHandler = () => {
    setConfirmPasswordIsValid(true);
  };

  return (
    <Card className="form-container">
      <div className="form">
        <h3>Signup</h3>
        <Form method="POST" onSubmit={formSubmitHandler} noValidate>
          <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            id="email"
            name="email"
            ref={emailInputRef}
            onChange={emailChangeHandler}
            style={!emailIsValid ? { border: "1px red solid" } : {}}
          />
          {!emailIsValid && (
            <p className="error-message">Enter a valid email.</p>
          )}
          <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            id="password"
            name="password"
            ref={passwordInputRef}
            onChange={passwordChangeHandler}
            style={!passwordIsValid ? { border: "1px red solid" } : {}}
          />
          {!passwordIsValid && (
            <p className="error-message">
              Password should be at least 5 characters.
            </p>
          )}
          <label htmlFor="confirmPassword">Confirm Password</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            id="confirmPassword"
            name="confirmPassword"
            ref={confirmPasswordInputRef}
            onChange={confirmPasswordChangeHandler}
            style={!confirmPasswordIsValid ? { border: "1px red solid" } : {}}
          />
          {!confirmPasswordIsValid && (
            <p className="error-message">
              Not matching with the entered password.
            </p>
          )}
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          <p>
            Already signed up? <Link to="/auth/login">Login</Link>
          </p>
        </Form>
      </div>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default SignupPage;

export const action = async ({ params, request }) => {
  const data = await request.formData();

  const signupData = {
    email: data.get("email"),
    password: data.get("password"),
    confirmPassword: data.get("confirmPassword"),
  };

  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/auth/signup", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(signupData),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  });

  console.log(res);
};
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting or what is the response you are receiving that's not the expected response? you can also have a look in my answer below if that somehow helps

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing an external package you're using, `formSubmitHandler` is responsible for submitting your form fields and sending the API request from your code, so your fetch request should be inside the `formSubmitHandler` since it's not calling `action()` anywhere else.

Why not just use the form fields and fetch request directly? Like below⬇️

```
const formSubmitHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const enteredEmail = emailInputRef.current.value;
    const enteredPassword = passwordInputRef.current.value;
    const enteredConfirmPassword = confirmPasswordInputRef.current.value;

    ...//all previous code

   else {
    const signupData = {
       email: enteredEmail,
       password: enteredPassword,
       confirmPassword: enteredConfirmPassword,
    };

    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:8080/auth/signup", {
       method: "POST",
       body: JSON.stringify(signupData),
       headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
       },
    });

    console.log(res);      
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem!

I was doing this:

The problem was that  component automatically submits the form to the action function. But with the onSubmit() event listener it was not doing so.